# QuickSort using first index as pivot not working

Tags: java, quicksort

Hey I've been trying to write up a quick sort program for my class using both a front end pivot and a back end pivot. The back end pivot works no problem, but when I tired modifying the code to work with a front end pivot, it won't completely sort the list.

Since this is for a school assignment, I don't want to just rip code from other sources. (I've found plenty of examples of working code but it's very different from mine, plus I'm trying to learn, not just copy paste.)

Here's my code for the front end pivot, let me know if you need more. Thanks. :)

```
public static int partitionPivotFront(int[] a, int lo, int hi)
{
  int pivot = a[lo];
  int i = hi - 1;

  for (int j = hi; j > lo; j--)
    {
    if (a[j] >= pivot)
      {
        i--;
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
      }
    }
    int temp = a[i + 1];
    a[i + 1] = a[lo];
    a[lo] = temp;
    return i + 1;
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend to learn how to use a debugger and step through your algorithm to find the bug.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I know how to use my debug tool, I just wasn't thinking about that.  Ill try that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your if statement and double check what are you comparing and what are you doing after. 
Since pivot is always first element, you want to compare if element is smaller than pivot and if it is put it before pivot.